# Linting only errors in VS Code

Tags: typescript, vue.js, visual-studio-code, ionic-framework

For some reason I always get an error in VS Code when trying to import types to test them in an Vue-Ionic App.
The tests are working, it's just an error while editing the code.
I've written down an example of the project structure and some example code.
Does anyone know, how to fix this error?

Error message:

```
Cannot find module '@/types.ts' or its corresponding type declarations. ts(2307)
```

Project structure:

```
├─ src
│  └─ types.ts
├─ tests
│  └─ unit
│     └─ types.spec.ts
├─ tsconfig.json
├─ tsconfig.node.json
├─ vite.config.ts
└─ vitest.config.ts
```

`types.ts`:

```
export class TestableType {}
```

`types.spec.ts`:

```
import { TestableType } from "@/types.ts";
```

`tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "target": "ESNext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "lib": ["ESNext", "DOM"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.d.ts", "src/**/*.tsx", "src/**/*.vue"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}
```

`tsconfig.node.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "composite": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "include": ["vite.config.ts"]
}
```

`vite.config.ts`:

```
import legacy from '@vitejs/plugin-legacy'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import path from 'path'
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    legacy()
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, './src'),
    }
  },
})
```

`vitest.config.ts`:

```
import { configDefaults, defineConfig } from 'vitest/config'
import path from 'path'

export default defineConfig({
  test: {
    exclude: [...configDefaults.exclude, 'packages/template/*'],
    globals: true,
    environment: 'jsdom',
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, './src'),
    }
  },
})
```

Comment: Try adding [`typeRoots`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#typeRoots) and add path `src/types.ts` in [`include`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#include) in `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: I added both, but nothing changed